# How do I solve IabHelper Error

Tags: java, android

I have an error on 264 and 163 of two file but in editor it's look fine

line 264 :

```
if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
```

line 163 :

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
```

I can't find why my activity unable to start
Logcat:

```
    1266-1266/com.exercise.AndroidHTML E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exercise.AndroidHTML/com.company.clipboard.AndroidHTMLActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.company.clipboard.util.IabHelper.startSetup(IabHelper.java:264)
at com.company.clipboard.AndroidHTMLActivity.onCreate(AndroidHTMLActivity.java:163)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at android.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at android.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the whole block of payment that contain line 163:

```
//=====================================================
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIHNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4G7ADCBtwKBrwDtUWVdLt6clZldCQGZxcyyWeeBp8vF/6qm7qCKuQPdXg6HB71hVu8lmcEO0VcyS2xpzXt03iW7LhKXRtDsxi5H9wHLESfY9SQUc0ugPD+n5nE+I6zCiB/RB2WscvZFa3JCiYRbmsvez+DwaQSHfq6CNUawl0fbz4NfJntZHKYHanm6PtjquO9JSj+Pa9PV38C3o5Y3ALCvPMCAwEAAQ==";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");
                // does the user have the premium upgrade?
                mIsPremium = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
                if (mIsPremium){
                    MasrafSeke(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM));
                }
                // update UI accordingly

                Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
        }
    };

    mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
                // give user access to premium content and update the UI
                Toast.makeText(AndroidHTMLActivity.this,"خرید موفق",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MasrafSeke(purchase);

            }
        }
    };


    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            }
            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you're getting a null pointer...so something wasn't initialized. Could you post some more code...could be mContext?

Comment: post the lines before 163

Comment: @petey : before 163 : `Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");`

Comment: Please post more of the code to the question

Comment: @petey : check it.please

Comment: in `mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);`   what is `this`?

Comment: @petey : this is a security code that use in payment process

Comment: @LocHa : I have not any other option

Comment: @LocHa : I run it on android ver.4.3 and it's work but when I use 4.1.1 I see this error

Answer (score 0):

Seems an issue of IabHelper. The method `queryIntentServices` returns a `null`, instead an empty list.

Try to update the code from this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
    // service available to handle that Intent
    mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
else {
    // no service available to handle that Intent
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onIabSetupFinished(
                new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE,
                "Billing service unavailable on device.")); 
    }
}
```

to this:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
List<ResolveInfo> intentServices = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0);

if (intentServices != null && intentServices.isEmpty() == false) {
    // service available to handle that Intent
    mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
else {
    // no service available to handle that Intent
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onIabSetupFinished(
                new IabResult(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE,
                "Billing service unavailable on device.")); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. IabHelper.java:798
IabHelper.java:626
IabHelper.java:655
AndroidHTMLActivity.java:139
IabHelper.java:290
AndroidHTMLActivity.java:130

Comment: Changing only the rows in the answer you can't receive this exception. Check if you have done other changes.

Comment: @Amir.KH:  It is another issue. For NullPointerException, Mattia is correct. You should create another question for IllegalStateException. One answer can't solve all issues